# Switch domain between 2 sites, one is Amazon EC2 ubuntu instance , another is hostgator

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, domain, host

There are two registered domain name, and I would like to switch the domain name between 2 sites.

The problems are :

1) in amazon Ubuntu, I follow the guidelines :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html 
however, when I connect to SFTP server , I can't access the /etc/sysconfig/network.

2) in hostgator , it is cpanel , any options is for replace the domain name

3) if I contact the support , besides the domain name, what else I need to provide?

Sorry for those basic question, I afraid I better to contact support but need some preparation before contact them. e.g. What is the steps to steps to change domain. Thanks a lot for helping.

**Updated:**

Thanks for reply, sorry for confusing. The idea is , there are two site ,with different host

```
site A | amazon EC2 ubuntu instance | www.domainA.com
site B | hostgator | www.domainB.com
```

right now I would like to change to like this:

when I enter domainB.com , it goes to site A , 
and enter domainA.com goes to site B.

===============================================

Seems have understand more now,

Is that mean:

I need to contact the Two DNS provider:

```
For the www.domainB.com , I need to provide the amazon instance detail e.g. public ip etc.. to the support

For the www.domainA.com , I need to provide the hostgator login to the support
```

And that's nothing to do for cpanel, aws instance setting...etc ..

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your question is still relatively unclear. I think the answer is "it depends on your applications and configuration".

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to look at your file permissions and SFTP server (ssh) configuration. Consider Using ssh to do it using vi.
2. I have no idea what cpanel has to do with domain names. Can you please clarify your question.
3. It depends what you're trying to achieve.

You need to describe what you're trying to achieve more carefully and precisely. If all you're trying to do it point a domain currently pointing at a shared host an AWS that's fairly trivial, a DNS change to your A record.

Comment: thanks, would you mind take a look at the updated question